# Memory game in Elm, randomized or shuffled grid

Tags: elm

I'm working on a memory game where the user is presented with a 5x5 grid of squares with 9 of them highlighted. The user then has to remember and select those 9 squares.

How do I generate the expected/winning board configuration?

Currently, I have have `Board` as a `List (List Bool)`

In an imperative language, like JS, I would just iterate over the grid 9 times randomly selecting a column and row index to mutate. That's not possible in Elm, so I'm a little stuck.

A couple strategies have come to mind:

**Strategy 1**

Generate a randomized grid

**Strategy 2**

Use `Array` and shuffle all coordinates, pick the first 9.

Note I also need a way to select the tile, so it's likely `Board` will become `List (List Tile)` where `Tile` is `{ x: Int, y: Int, selected: Bool}`.

I've already written the game in vanilla JS. You can try it out here: http://mruzekw.github.io/recall/

Here is the code I've written so far somewhat implementing strategy :

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.App as App
import Random
import Random.Array
import Array exposing (..)


-- model


type alias Board =
    Array (Array Bool)


type alias Tile =
    { x : Int
    , y : Int
    , selected : Bool
    }


type alias Model =
    { board : Board
    , expectedBoard : Board
    , gameOver : Bool
    , playerWon : Bool
    , turnCount : Int
    }


initModel : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
initModel =
    ( { board = generateSquareMatrix 5 False
      , expectedBoard = Array.fromList []
      , gameOver = False
      , playerWon = False
      , turnCount = 0
      }
    , Cmd.none
    )


generateSquareMatrix : Int -> Bool -> Array (Array Bool)
generateSquareMatrix num value =
    Array.repeat num (Array.repeat num value)



-- update


type Msg
    = SelectTile Bool
    | RestartGame
    | SuffleBoard
    | NewBoard (Array (Array Bool))


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case (Debug.log "msg" msg) of
        SelectTile tile ->
            ( { model
                | turnCount = model.turnCount + 1
              }
            , Cmd.none
            )

        RestartGame ->
            ( { model
                | turnCount = 0
              }
            , Cmd.none
            )

        SuffleBoard ->
            ( model, Random.generate NewBoard (Random.Array.shuffle model.board) )

        NewBoard newBoard ->
            ( { model | board = newBoard }
            , Cmd.none
            )



-- view


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [ class "scoreboard" ]
        [ h1 [] [ text "Recall" ]
        , grid model
        , button [ onClick SuffleBoard ] [ text "New Board" ]
        , p [] [ text (toString model) ]
        ]


grid : Model -> Html Msg
grid model =
    div [ class "recall-grid" ]
        (List.map
            (\row ->
                div
                    [ class "recall-grid-row" ]
                    (List.map
                        (\tile ->
                            div [ class "recall-grid-tile", onClick (SelectTile tile) ] []
                        )
                        (Array.toList row)
                    )
            )
            (Array.toList model.board)
        )



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


main : Program Never
main =
    App.program
        { init = initModel
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strategy 2 works just fine since it will guarantee uniqueness of the random elements.

When dealing with randomness, it is best to build complex generators out of simple generators using generator mapping functions. This frees you up from having to keep track of a random seed inside the actual generator code.

The first generator we need is one that builds that list of array indexes, which I'll describe as a tuple of `(Int, Int)`.

```elm
indexGenerator : Int -> Int -> Random.Generator (Array (Int, Int))
indexGenerator edgeSize sampleSize =
    List.map (\i -> List.map2 (,) (List.repeat edgeSize i) [0..(edgeSize-1)]) [0..(edgeSize-1)]
        |> List.concat
        |> Array.fromList
        |> Random.Array.shuffle
        |> Random.map (Array.slice 0 sampleSize)
```

Now we can use `Random.map`, along with your initial matrix of Falses to build the `squareMatrixGenerator`:

```elm
squareMatrixGenerator : Int -> Int -> Bool -> Random.Generator (Array (Array Bool))
squareMatrixGenerator edgeSize sampleSize value =
    let
        initialMatrix =
            Array.repeat edgeSize (Array.repeat edgeSize value)
        invertPoint (x, y) =
            Array.Extra.update x (Array.Extra.update y not)
        indexes =
            indexGenerator edgeSize sampleSize
    in
        Random.map (Array.foldl invertPoint initialMatrix) indexes
```

The above code also relies on the [`elm-community/array-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/array-extra/1.0.1/Array-Extra) package for the array updates.

You can then use it during `init` by passing a seed to `Random.step`, and by the `ShuffleBoard` Msg when using `Random.generate`. For example:

```elm
ShuffleBoard ->
    ( model, Random.generate NewBoard (squareMatrixGenerator 9 5 False) )
```

Comment: Thanks, Chad! There's a lot to parse here. Let me run with it see how it goes. I'll comment if I have any follow up questions.